# Benefits of sleeping in a sitting posture

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-practicalities, well-being, sleep, technique

Occasionally some buddhists monks will take up the practice of only sleeping in a sitting posture for an extended duration of time - sometimes up to 3 months.

- What are the meditational (preferably insight-meditational) benefits of such practice?
- How would one undertake such practice regarding posture and technique?

I read that one could start sleeping 1-2 hours in sitting posture and then move to a lying posture. Then slowly increase the time sleeping in sitting posture while reducing the time spent sleeping in lying posture.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A good question, @Sri Lanka !

Answer (score 3):

The practice of sleeping in a sitting posture can be explained as one of the 13 [Dhutanga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhutanga).

> 13. Sitter's Practice (nesajjik'anga) — living in the three postures of walking, standing and sitting and never lying down.

The advantages of sleeping less as described by the Buddha can be found in [Jāgariyasutta](https://suttacentral.net/en/iti47)

> **Vigilance**
>
> This was said by the Lord…
>
> "Bhikkhus, a bhikkhu should be vigilant; he should live mindful, clearly comprehending, concentrated, happy and calm, and should know when it is suitable to cultivate those things that are wholesome. Bhikkhus, for a bhikkhu who is vigilant and living thus, one of two fruits is to be expected: final knowledge here and now or, there being some residual defilement, the state of non-returning."
>
> You vigilant ones hear this:
>   Wake up, you who are asleep!
>   Vigilance is better than sleep:
>   There is no fear for the vigilant.
>
> One who is vigilant and mindful,
>   Comprehending and concentrated,
>   Joyful and calm in his thoughts,
>   By rightly investigating the Dhamma
>   With unified mind, will in time
>   Destroy the darkness of ignorance.
>
> Therefore be devoted to vigilance,
>   An ardent, discerning, meditative bhikkhu.
>   Having severed the fetter of birth and decay,
>   One may here and now attain
>   Enlightenment which is supreme.

Note that the pali word 'Jāgaro' which means 'deprive sleep' is translated as 'vigilant' in the above sutta translation.

Comment: Thank you Sajeewa, for the *the thirteen dhutanga practices*.

Comment: Thank you Sajeewa, you gave me more information and understanding of something. with metta... _/\_

Answer (score 2):

From Vissudhimagga:

> The benefits are these. The mental shackle described thus, “He dwells
>   indulging in the pleasure of lying prone, the pleasure of lolling, the
>   pleasure of torpor”,  is  severed;  his  state  is  suitable  for 
>   devotion  to  any  meditation  subject;  his deportment  inspires 
>   confidence;  his  state  favours  the  application  of  energy;  he
>   develops the right practice.
>
> The adept that can place crosswise
>   His feet to rest upon his thighs
>   And sit with back erect shall make
>   Foul Mára’s evil heart to quake.
>   No more in supine joys to plump
>   And wallow in lethargic dump;
>   Who sits for rest and finds it good
>   Shines forth in the Ascetics’ Wood.
>   The happiness and bliss it brings
>   Has naught to do with worldly things;
>    So must the sitter’s vow befit
>   The manners of a man of wit.

Greed subsides.

Thus the Sitter's Practise is the only recommended practise connected to energy.

Answer (score 0):

There are several online articles that relate to the question of sleeping upright:

[Why do Buddhist monks sleep upright?](https://dharmafolk.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/why-do-buddhist-monks-sleep-upright/)

[Why do Buddhist monks sleep upright?](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/8112619.stm)

[How to Sleep Sitting Up](http://www.theminimalists.com/drew/)